# Mapping elixir absinthe input_object to single data structure

Tags: elixir, absinthe

Is there some way to map an input_object into a single data structure?

```
  input_object(:numrange) do
    field :start, non_null(:integer) do
      resolve(fn field, _, _ ->
        ...
      end)
    end
    field :end, non_null(:integer) do
      resolve(fn field, _, _ ->
        ...
      end)
    end
  end
```

And then have it parsed as [start, end] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to define this at the input_object level. However, there are a few different ways to handle parameter transformation.

## 1. Change your business logic

You can just change the contracts within your service layer to handle an object instead of an array.

```elixir
# Inside of some module

def my_functon(attrs, other, params) do
  formatted_attrs = case attrs do
    %{range: %{start: startrange, end: endrange}} ->
      %{attrs | range: [startrange, endrange]}
    _ -> 
      attrs
  end
  # ...
end
```

## 2. Handle the input object where it is passed by args in the schema

You can transform the arguments when they are submitted

```elixir
# Some graphql definition

field(:my_field, :my_object) do
  arg(:range, non_null(:numrange))
  resolve(fn parent, %{range: %{start: rstart, end: rend}} = args, ctx ->
    new_args = %{args | range: [rstart, rend]}
    SomeModule.my_function(new_attrs, parent, ctx)
  end)
end
```

## 3. Create a middleware

You can create an [Absinthe.Middleware](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Middleware.html) to transform arguments when they are submitted

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.NumrangeTransform do
  @behaviour Absinthe.Middleware

  @impl Absinthe.Middleware
  def call(%Absinthe.Resolution{arguments: args} = res, opts) do
    field = Keyword.fetch!(opts, :field)
    new_args = case Map.get(args, field) do
      %{start: rstart, end: rend} ->
         Map.put(args, field, [rstart, rend])
      _ ->
        args
    end

    %{res | arguments: new_args}
  end
end
```

Then in your schema definition:

```elixir
field(:my_field, :type) do
  middleware(MyApp.NumrangeTransform, field: :range)
  arg(:range, :numrange)
  # ...
end
```

The Middleware will transform the args for you without having to write transformation logic everywhere

## 4. Create a custom scalar type

[custom scalar](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Schema.Notation.html#scalar/3) types can be defined in Absinthe:

```elixir
# In some schema definition

scalar :numrange, name: "NumRange" do
  description("A number range of integers m..n")
  serialize([rstart, rend]) when is_integer(rstart) and is_integer(rend) do
    rstart <> ".." <> rend
  end

  parse(&do_parse/1)

  defp do_parse(%Absinthe.Blueprint.Input.String{value: range_str}) do
    with [s_str, e_str] <- String.split(range_str, ".."),
       {rstart, _} <- Integer.parse(s_str),
       {rend, _} <- Integer.parse(e_str) do
      {:ok, [rstart, rend]}
    else
      _ -> :error
    end
  end

  def do_parse(%Absinthe.Blueprint.Input.Null{}), do: {:ok, nil}
  def do_parse(_), do: :error
end
```

Then it is added somewhere in the schema

```elixir
field(:my_field, :type) do
  arg(:range, non_null(:numrange))
  # ...
end
```

And the GraphQL looks something like this:

```graphql
query SomeQuery {
  myField(range:"1..3")
}
```

This is probably the least attractive option as it creates a non-standard way of both presenting and accepting number ranges for any front-end application. However, if this is not a public API that is accessed by third-party applications, there should be no issue with doing it.

## Conclusion

There are many ways to define and handle parameter transformation in your input arguments. There may be other solutions that I haven't mentioned. You could probably do something pretty crazy by writing a custom [Absinthe.Phase](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Phase.html), but that is a complex endeavour that would likely be too heavy-handed for something this simple.